# HTML/CSS/JSでまだら模様の波を実装したい

Tags: javascript, html, css

#### 質問の背景

HTML/CSS/JSを使用した静的コーディングでWebサイトを制作しています。
その過程で、canvasで単色の波のアニメーションを使用しているのですが、
まだら模様で波を実装しなければならない箇所があり、お知恵を借りられれば幸いです。

#### 実現したいこと

[波打つ（1 つ 重なりなし） | 動くWebデザインアイディア帳](https://coco-factory.jp/ugokuweb/move02/5-10/)

添付画像のようなまだら模様を、上記と同じ動きの波で実装したいです。

[image: 添付画像のようなまだら模様を、1と同じ動きの波で実装したいです。]

皆さまが上記を実装するとなった場合、どういった方法で実装するか
教えていただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

`context.fill();`を使って単色で塗りつぶしている処理を`context.drawImage(overImage, 0, 0);`で画像を描画する処理に書き換えることで実現できます。

末尾のサンプルコードはリンク先のJavaScriptを書き直した全文です。
変更点をピックアップします。

- 最初に画像をロードします。

```
let overImage = new Image();
overImage.src = "colorful-abstract-art-background.jpg";
let backImage = new Image();
backImage.src = "copy-space-wall-texture-for-backgrounds.jpg";
```

- 背景画像を使用する場合は`draw`関数の`clearRect`を`drawImage`に変更します。

```
    // キャンバスの描画をクリア
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(backImage, 0, 0);
```

- `drawWave`関数で`beginPath`する前に`save`しておき、`closePath`した後に画像を描画します。

```
    context.save();
    context.beginPath(); //パスの開始
    // (中略)
    context.closePath() //パスを閉じる
    //context.fill(); //波を塗りつぶす
    context.clip();
    context.drawImage(overImage, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
```

**実行結果の例**

[image: まだら模様]

下記クレジットの画像を使用しました。

[著作者：rawpixel.com](https://jp.freepik.com/free-photo/colorful-abstract-art-background_4102535.htm#query=%E8%83%8C%E6%99%AF%E7%B4%A0%E6%9D%90&position=0&from_view=keyword&track=sph)／出典：Freepik
著作者：[Freepik](https://jp.freepik.com/free-photo/copy-space-wall-texture-for-backgrounds_10980237.htm#query=%E8%83%8C%E6%99%AF%E7%B4%A0%E6%9D%90&position=7&from_view=keyword&track=sph)

**サンプルコード**

あらかじめ画像をダウンロードして適切なフォルダに配置しておいてください。

```
var unit = 100,
    canvasList, // キャンバスの配列
    info = {}, // 全キャンバス共通の描画情報
    colorList; // 各キャンバスの色情報

let overImage = new Image();
overImage.src = "colorful-abstract-art-background.jpg";
let backImage = new Image();
backImage.src = "copy-space-wall-texture-for-backgrounds.jpg";

/**
 * Init function.
 * 
 * Initialize variables and begin the animation.
 */
function init() {
    info.seconds = 0;
    info.t = 0;
    canvasList = [];
    colorList = [];
    // canvas1個めの色指定
    canvasList.push(document.getElementById("waveCanvas"));
    colorList.push(['#43c0e4']);
  // 各キャンバスの初期化
    for(var canvasIndex in canvasList) {
        var canvas = canvasList[canvasIndex];
        canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth; //Canvasのwidthをウィンドウの幅に合わせる
        canvas.height = 200;//波の高さ
        canvas.contextCache = canvas.getContext("2d");
    }
    // 共通の更新処理呼び出し
    update();
}

function update() {
    for(var canvasIndex in canvasList) {
        var canvas = canvasList[canvasIndex];
        // 各キャンバスの描画
        draw(canvas, colorList[canvasIndex]);
    }
    // 共通の描画情報の更新
    info.seconds = info.seconds + .014;
    info.t = info.seconds*Math.PI;
    // 自身の再起呼び出し
    setTimeout(update, 35);
}

/**
 * Draw animation function.
 * 
 * This function draws one frame of the animation, waits 20ms, and then calls
 * itself again.
 */
function draw(canvas, color) {
    // 対象のcanvasのコンテキストを取得
    var context = canvas.contextCache;
    // キャンバスの描画をクリア
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(backImage, 0, 0);

    //波を描画 drawWave(canvas, color[数字（波の数を0から数えて指定）], 透過, 波の幅のzoom,波の開始位置の遅れ )
    drawWave(canvas, color[0], 1, 3, 0);//drawWave(canvas, color[0],0.5, 3, 0);とすると透過50%の波が出来る
}

/**
* 波を描画
* drawWave(色, 不透明度, 波の幅のzoom, 波の開始位置の遅れ)
*/
function drawWave(canvas, color, alpha, zoom, delay) {
    var context = canvas.contextCache;
    context.fillStyle = color;//塗りの色
    context.globalAlpha = alpha;
    context.save();
    context.beginPath(); //パスの開始
    drawSine(canvas, info.t / 0.5, zoom, delay);
    context.lineTo(canvas.width + 10, canvas.height); //パスをCanvasの右下へ
    context.lineTo(0, canvas.height); //パスをCanvasの左下へ
    context.closePath() //パスを閉じる
    //context.fill(); //波を塗りつぶす
    context.clip();
    context.drawImage(overImage, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
}

/**
 * Function to draw sine
 * 
 * The sine curve is drawn in 10px segments starting at the origin. 
 * drawSine(時間, 波の幅のzoom, 波の開始位置の遅れ)
 */
function drawSine(canvas, t, zoom, delay) {
    var xAxis = Math.floor(canvas.height/2);
    var yAxis = 0;
    var context = canvas.contextCache;
    // Set the initial x and y, starting at 0,0 and translating to the origin on
    // the canvas.
    var x = t; //時間を横の位置とする
    var y = Math.sin(x)/zoom;
    context.moveTo(yAxis, unit*y+xAxis); //スタート位置にパスを置く

    // Loop to draw segments (横幅の分、波を描画)
    for (i = yAxis; i <= canvas.width + 10; i += 10) {
        x = t+(-yAxis+i)/unit/zoom;
        y = Math.sin(x - delay)/3;
        context.lineTo(i, unit*y+xAxis);
    }
}

init();
```